# ImportError: cannot import name 'ExifTag' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I converted my python file to .exe using pyinstaller, but when opening the .exe this message appears in cmd, what can it be?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ExifTag' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90162\PIL\__init__.pyc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't have `Pillow` installed as a module before packing it. Use the following commands before packing it again.

```
pip install Pillow
```

```
pip install Pillow_SIMD
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add ExifTags as a hidden import argument, it will work.

`pyinstaller --hidden-import="PIL.ExifTags" file.py`